# New display format needed: "drag box"

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, display

I want to create a new display type, especially for numbers or text, but potentially for arbitrary objects as well. I want a "drag box" where not all of the number (object) is visible, but dragging left and right on the object itself slides it left and right (or in a generalized form both x and y).

No scroll bars should be visible, and it should be tightly integrated much like `Framed` so that it can be used in different places without difficulty.

In [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4991939#4991939) Szabolcs showed how to get the basic functionality.  However, there are problems with this implementation as he notes:

1. the `N[Pi,100]` shouldn't be recalculated constantly
2. ... Dynamic doesn't work inside the `ScrollPosition` setting ...
3. when the mouse leaves the region, it stops working, and for good usability it shouldn't

I don't observe #3 on my system (Win7/mma7) but I do note another problem:  Dragging the text left (looking at the least significant digits) it is possible to drag the object completely out of frame.  Dragging it right does not move it out of frame but causes a memory of the drag such that it appears "stuck" when you start dragging left, though it eventually moves.

- How can this function be implemented most efficiently and flexibly?
- Can it be made to work inside a `Text` object the way `Frame` does?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood very well the subtleties. Wouldn't for example the N[Pi, 100] recalculation be fixed by injecting it with `With` or something? Btw, Win7/mma 8, when I drag it right to the most significant digits I can drag it out of frame, but not to the left. I mean, you have to drag it inside the cell for it to work

Comment: @Rojo What I meant was that I was lazy to fix up the solution there.  These were problems that need to be fixed.  Of course it can be injected with `With`, I just didn't do it on the first try.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a more robust version of Rojo's answer:

```
BeginPackage["DragPane`"];
DragPane::usage = "implements a draggable Pane";
BeginPackage["`Package`"];
DragPaneDynamicModule::usage = "the dynamic module used by DragPane";
EndPackage[];
Begin["`Private`"];
Options[DragPaneDynamicModule] =
  Join[
   Options[Pane],
   {
    AutoAction -> False
    }
   ];
DragPaneDynamicModule[
   exp_,
   {width_, height_},
   ops : OptionsPattern[]
   ] :=
  With[
   {
    boxSize =
     {#[[1]], 3 + Total@#[[2 ;;]]} &@First@
       FrontEndExecute@
        GetBoundingBoxSizePacket[
         Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[exp]],
          "Output",
          PageWidth -> \[Infinity],
          ShowCellBracket -> False,
           CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
          ]
         ]
    },
   DynamicModule[
    {
     scrollX = 0., scrollY = 0.,
     maxWidth =
      If[! NumericQ@width,
       boxSize[[1]],
       Max@{boxSize[[1]], width}
       ],
     boxWidth =
      If[! NumericQ@width, Min@{boxSize[[1]], 360} , width],
      maxHeight =
      If[! NumericQ@height,
       boxSize[[2]],
       Max@{boxSize[[2]], height}
       ],
     boxHeight =
      If[! NumericQ@height, Min@{boxSize[[2]], 360} , height],
     setXScroll,
     setYScroll,
     getXScroll,
     getYScroll,
     scrolling = False,
     refWidth, refX,
     refHeight, refY
     },
    Pane[
     EventHandler[
       Pane[
        Pane[exp, 2*boxSize, Alignment -> {Left, Top}],
        Full,
        ScrollPosition :>
         Dynamic[
          If[
           TrueQ[scrolling],
           {
            setXScroll[],
            setYScroll[]
            },
           {scrollX, scrollY}
           ],
          Function[
           scrollX =
            Clip[#[[1]], {0., Max@{maxWidth - boxWidth, 0.}}];
           scrollY =
            Clip[#[[2]], {0., Max@{maxHeight - boxHeight, 0.}}];
           ],
          TrackedSymbols :> {scrollX, scrollY}
          ],
         Alignment -> {Left, Top}
        ],
       {
        If[TrueQ@OptionValue[AutoAction],
          "MouseEntered",
          "MouseDown"
          ] :>
         (
          refX = scrollX;
          refY = scrollY;
          {refWidth, refHeight} = MousePosition["ScreenAbsolute"];
          scrolling = True
          ),
        If[TrueQ@OptionValue[AutoAction],
          "MouseMoved",
          "MouseDragged"
          ] :>
         (
          If[! AllTrue[{refWidth, refHeight}, NumericQ],
           refX = scrollX;
           refY = scrollY;
           {refWidth, refHeight} = MousePosition["ScreenAbsolute"];
           scrolling = True
           ];
          setXScroll[];
          ),
        If[TrueQ@OptionValue[AutoAction],
          "MouseExited",
          "MouseUp"
          ] :>
         (
          scrolling = False;
          setXScroll[];
          setYScroll[];
          Clear[refWidth, refHeight, refX, refY];
          )
        }
       ] // MouseAppearance[#, "PanView"] &,
     FilterRules[
      {
       ImageSize ->
        Dynamic[{boxWidth, boxHeight}],
       ops
       },
      Options[Pane]
      ]
     ],
    Initialization :>
     {
      getXScroll[x_] :=
       Clip[
        refX + refWidth - x,
        {0., Max@{maxWidth - boxWidth, 0.}}
        ];
      getXScroll[] :=

       getXScroll[First@MousePosition["ScreenAbsolute"]],
      setXScroll[x___] :=
       scrollX = getXScroll[x],
      getYScroll[y_] :=
       Clip[
        refY + refHeight - y,
        {0., Max@{maxHeight - boxHeight, 0.}}
        ];
      getYScroll[] :=

       getYScroll[Last@MousePosition["ScreenAbsolute"]],
      setYScroll[y___] :=
       scrollY = getYScroll[y]
      }
    ]
   ];

Options[DragPane] =
  Options[DragPaneDynamicModule];
DragPane[
   exp_,
   w : _?NumericQ | Automatic,
   ops : OptionsPattern[]
   ] :=
  DragPane[exp, {w, Automatic}, ops];
DragPane[
   exp_,
   ops : OptionsPattern[]
   ] :=
  DragPane[exp,
    OptionValue[ImageSize],
   ops
   ];
Format[dp : 
    DragPane[exp_, {width_, height_}, ops : OptionsPattern[]], 
   StandardForm] :=
  Interpretation[
   DragPaneDynamicModule[exp, {width, height}, ops],
   dp
   ];
End[];
EndPackage[]
```

1. The scrolling is more stable
2. It only displays as the scrollable form. That is, its expression form remains `DragPane`.
3. It supports scrolling in y as well, but only if there's space
4. It can take `AppearanceElements -> "ResizeArea"`
5. I added `AutoAction` as a bit of a joke

Here's a good example:

```
DragPane[
 ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}],
  Scaled[2]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: ssdsd]

Comment: I wasn't expected an update on this. :-)  This *does* work well. This is a nice addition to our output formatting options and I hope people make use of it; I know I will.  Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure I understood the concerns, so let me know how this works. The `N[Pi , 50]` isn't recalculated since `Dragger` doesn't have the attributes `HoldFirst` or family. Seems it can be dragged anywhere. And I don't know about the rest.

```
Dragger[exp_, size_] :=
 With[{maxsize = 
    First[ImageSize /. Options[Rasterize@exp, ImageSize]] - 0.95 size},
   DynamicModule[{x = 0., b = False, ref}, 
   MouseAppearance[
    EventHandler[
     Pane[Pane[exp, 100000], ImageSize -> size, 
      ScrollPosition :> 
       Dynamic[{If[b, 
          Clip[x + ref - First@MousePosition["ScreenAbsolute"], {0., 
            maxsize}], x], 0.}, 
        Null &]], {"MouseDown" :> (ref = 
         First@MousePosition["ScreenAbsolute"]; b = True), 
      "MouseUp" :> (b = False;
        x = 
         Clip[x + ref - First@MousePosition["ScreenAbsolute"], {0., 
           maxsize}])}], "FrameLRResize"]]]
```

I thought this would be inefficient in that it would update for every change in MousePosition, so I was ready to wrap a Refresh such as  `If[b, Refresh[..., UpdateInterval:>0.05]...`, but in my tests it is smarter than I thought and doesn't try to update when `b` is `False`

So you should run `Dragger[N[Pi, 50], 100]` to test it

Comment: This snaps back to the original position when I let go of the mouse button (actually when a move a pixel or two after).  Is that the intent?  Also, I can still drag the text out of frame when dragging while moving the mouse left.  +1 for working on this however. :-)

Comment: No, it wasn't the intent. But I'm doing this through remote desktop on a clumsy connection so it's hard to see the subtleties of the interactivity. Just now I understood what you meant with the dragging left issue. It doesn't seem to be snapping back to the original position for me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Editing to add an ugly patch for the left dragging thing

Comment: You don't really need `:>` in `ScrollPosition`.  `->` will do.

Answer (score 4):

In versions 10.4+, you can use [`DynamicImage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicImage.html):

```
img = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], Scaled[2]];

DynamicImage[img, ImageSize -> 200, ZoomFactor -> .5, 
   ZoomCenter -> {Left, Top}, AppearanceElements -> {"Pan"}]
```

[image]