# How to organise functions inside a package instead of the initialisation of a DynamicModule?

Tags: dynamic, packages, gui-construction

I want to know how to write clean code of a big DynamicModul for a complex GUI which should be deployed as a CDF. I want to split the dynamic module into several smaller DynamicModuls and Functions.

Here is an example package:

```
(* ::Package:: *)
ClearAll["test`*", "test`*`*"]


BeginPackage["test`"];

testgui::usage="testing gui with package";

Begin["`Private`"];

guicolor = ColorData[3];
topcolor = Red;
topcoloractive = ColorData["GrayTones"][0.4];
guitextcolor = White;
guifont = FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue";
buttoncolor = guicolor[5];

view1 = DynamicModule[{var1 = 1}, Column[{Button["var1 =10", var1 = 10], Dynamic@var1}], InheritScope -> True];
view2 = DynamicModule[{var1 = 1}, Column[{Button["var1 =20", var1 = 20], Dynamic@var1}], InheritScope -> True];

testgui := Framed@DynamicModule[{stream, viewbutton, view = 1, toprow, mainview, var1 = 1},
  Column[{Dynamic@toprow,
    Dynamic@mainview[view]
  }],

  Initialization :> (
    mainview = <|1 -> view1, 2 -> view2|>;

    viewbutton[text_, viewnumber_] := Button[Style[text, guitextcolor, guifont,
      FontWeight -> Dynamic[If[view == viewnumber, Bold]]],
      Dynamic[view = viewnumber], Background -> Dynamic[If[view == viewnumber, topcoloractive, topcolor]],
      FrameMargins -> Medium, ContentPadding -> True, Method -> "Queued", Appearance -> None, ImageSize -> 100];

    toprow = Grid[{{Dynamic@viewbutton["View 1", 1], Dynamic@viewbutton["View 2", 2]}}, Spacings -> {0, Automatic}];
  )
]


End[];

EndPackage[ ];
```

I saved this package code as "test.wl" and use Get to test it:

```
packagepath = NotebookDirectory[] <> "test.wl"
Get[packagepath]
testgui
```

The GUI looks like this and works as expected:

[image: The GUI]

My specific questions are:

1.) How can I move the function viewbutton out from Initialization?

Simply copying the function outside of Initialization does not work. Also when it is wrapped inside another DynamicModule with InheritScope -> True.

2.) In general, what is the best way to organise projects with complex custom GUIs inside a package? With the aim to have small individual parts which can be tested and developed individually.

I am thinking about making view1 and view2 also modular and containing several smaller DynamicModules and use functions similar to the viewbutton function inside view1 and view2.

Comment: slightly related: [How can I include functions from a package into a CDF file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86674/5478)

Comment: No, that works for "normal" functions but not for functions which are "dynamic" itself. It does not work with the viewbutton function, or at least did not get it to work.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see. Well, the standard way is move `viewbutton` and define it as `viewbutton[text_, viewnumber_, Dynamic[view_], ...]`

Comment: Ah ok thanks, this led me on the right path. I am almost there, and will continue working on it on Tuesday. Is Dynamic as a function argument documented somewhere?

Comment: @gogoolplex almost anything can be a function argument. Do some searching on the site for defining `DownValues`. The only real thing to watch out is `HoldPattern`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few aspects:

- gui implementation (I'm about to tackle it)
- gui generation (see b3m2a1's answer)
- dependencies management

  (see `SaveDefinitions` or [How can I include functions from a package into a CDF file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86674/5478))

- a lot of tiny idioms I'm not ready to show my approach to but they are briefly summarized in e.g.:

  [WTC 2017 talk "Building Maintainable Dynamic Interfaces" - Lou D'Andria](https://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2017/presentations/#friday)

About implementation:

The solution to how to make your code more modularized is to pass relevant variables around with e.g.: `topRow[Dynamic[view_]]:=...`. This is a 'proper way' to do this, the way the WRI advertises. It is fine but can be cumbersome for larger projects.

Notice that `Dynamic` does not do any magic tricks here, we use it because it is `HoldAll`. You could use `Hold` instead or `SetAttributes[topRow, HoldAll]` and skipp `Dynamic`. `Dynamic` is just more readable than `Hold` and more convenient than attributes approach.

```
BeginPackage["Test`"];

ClearAll["Test`*", "Test`*`*"]
TestGui::usage = "TestGui[], testing gui with package";

Begin["`Private`"];

(*misc*)
$guicolor = ColorData[3];
$topcolor = Red;
$topcoloractive = ColorData["GrayTones"][0.4];
$guitextcolor = White;
$guifont = FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue";
$buttoncolor = $guicolor[5];


TestGui[] := Framed@DynamicModule[
    { view = 1, var1 = 1},
    Column[{
      topRow[Dynamic[view]],
      mainView[Dynamic[{view, var1}]]
      }]
   (* , SaveDefinitions -> True *) 
   (* uncomment this if you are not going to manage this yourself*)
];

mainView[Dynamic[{view_, var_}]] := PaneSelector[
   {1 -> view1[Dynamic[var]],
    2 -> view2[Dynamic[var]]
    },
   Dynamic[view]
   ];

topRow[Dynamic[view_]] := Module[{button1, button2}
, button1 = viewButton[Dynamic[view], "View 1", 1]
; button2 = viewButton[Dynamic[view], "View 2", 2]

; Grid[{{ button1, button2 }}, Spacings -> {0, Automatic} ]

]; (*Module here is only for educational purposes, for such simple element it does not help with anything as one can see in other functions. *)

view1[Dynamic[var_]] := Column[{
    Button["var1 =10", var = 10],
    Dynamic@var
    }];

view2[Dynamic[var_]] := Column[{
    Button["var1 =20", var = 20],
    Dynamic@var,
    "This one has a string here just to justify existance of separate \
view2"
    }];

viewButton[Dynamic[view_], text_, viewnumber_] := Button[
   Style[text, $guitextcolor, $guifont, 
    FontWeight -> Dynamic[If[view == viewnumber, Bold]]], 
   view = viewnumber,
   Background -> 
    Dynamic[If[view == viewnumber, $topcoloractive, $topcolor]], 
   FrameMargins -> Medium, ContentPadding -> True, Method -> "Queued",
    Appearance -> None, ImageSize -> 100
   ];




End[];

EndPackage[];
```

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/blob/master/BlockBuilder.m) an example of a pretty complex interface system built on variable passing and modularization (I'm sure you have a collection of your own you could show too). It doesn't protect against restarts, though. There's also [this](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/blob/master/Sheepshead.wl) for making a little card game. Just thought it might be nice to link to some more examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is pretty much what I used after your comment above. The only thing which I found useful and were not obvious for me was to also use stuff like `topRow[Dynamic[view_]] := Module[...]` or `topRow[Dynamic[view_]] := DynamicModule[...]` depending on the application. In addition its good to know that for example `topRow[Dynamic[view_Integer]]` does not work but `topRow[Dynamic[view_?IntegerQ]]` does.

Comment: @gogoolplex I added a note about `Dynamic` and a `Module` example. Yes `?IntegerQ` forces evaluation to check condition which is why it works even for held `Dynamic` content.

Comment: Thank for the answer. I have come to expect that we should use `Dynamic` for displaying things, except for the first argument of controls. So I was confused about this usage in `f[Dynamic[arg_]]:=definition`. I now realize that this `Dynamic` is there just because of its `HoldFirst` attribute. In fact you can change most of the `Dynamic`s above with `Hold`s, and it works just as well. I prefer to use `Hold`. `Dynamic` is already quite complex as it is.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino yes, sorry I didn't put this comment from the beginning. Let me know if enything else is not clear or is there something that should but wasn't addressed. p.s. I like to use `Dynamic` when it comes to passing DynamicModule or gui related variables and to use `HoldAll/Hold` approach for purely kernel functions.

Answer (score 3):

#### Format-level Approach

There are a few ways to do this. In my mind, the best way to handle this, in my mind, is to use an object-oriented approach. For this we define a function at package level that will build the GUI, but attach it as a `Format`-form to an exposed symbol. For instance I do that [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167039/38205). A toy example would look like this:

```
BeginPackage["GUI`"];
(* Exposed functions *)
GUI::usage = "GUI object";
(* Package level functions *)
BeginPackage["`Package`"];
guiImp1::usage = "row 1";
guiImp2::usage = "row 2";
makeGUI::usage = "builds the GUI";
EndPackage[];
(* Implementation *)
Begin["`Private`"];
guiImp1[] := {"lololol"};
guiImp2[] := {"lol2"};
makeGUI[ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  DynamicModule[{$packageLoaded},
   Dynamic@
    Framed[
     If[$packageLoaded,
      Grid[{
        guiImp1[],
        guiImp2[]
        },
       Alignment -> Left],
      "GUI package not loaded."
      ],
     ops,
     RoundingRadius -> 5, Background -> GrayLevel[.98], 
     FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[.8]
     ],
   Initialization :>
    {
     $packageLoaded :=
      DownValues[makeGUI] =!= {}
     }
   ];
Format[e : GUI[ops : OptionsPattern[]]] :=
  Interpretation[
   makeGUI[ops],
   e
   ];
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

This is also nice because it makes it copy-cleanly. For instance if I load that, run `GUI[FrameStyle -> Pink]` and copy the result it returns `` GUI`GUI[FrameStyle -> RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0.5]] ``

#### Package-protected

We could also drop the `Format` stuff from that and simply provide `makeGUI` as the top-level. The important thing to note is that it checks the loading-status of the package. If it's not loaded we don't want it to return a string of errors or pink boxes.

```
BeginPackage["GUI`"];
(* Exposed functions *)
GUI::usage = "builds the GUI";
(* Package level functions *)
BeginPackage["`Package`"];
guiImp1::usage = "row 1";
guiImp2::usage = "row 2";
EndPackage[];
(* Implementation *)
Begin["`Private`"];
guiImp1[] := {"lololol"};
guiImp2[] := {"lol2"};
GUI[ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  DynamicModule[{$packageLoaded},
   Dynamic@
    Framed[
     If[$packageLoaded,
      Grid[{
        guiImp1[],
        guiImp2[]
        },
       Alignment -> Left],
      "GUI package not loaded."
      ],
     ops,
     RoundingRadius -> 5, Background -> GrayLevel[.98], 
     FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[.8]
     ],
   Initialization :>
    {
     $packageLoaded :=
      DownValues[GUI] =!= {}
     }
   ];
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

#### Auto-loading

Sometimes you just want a GUI that stores its entire implementation. If we want that we can adapt the either approach pretty trivially using [`SaveDefinitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SaveDefinitions.html). The only place where we need to be sneaky is wrapping our argument in a `DynamicModule` that doesn't do anything and then using `Dynamic@Refresh[..., None]` so that the definitions are saved but our function is only called once. For instance we can do:

```
BeginPackage["GUI`"];
(* Exposed functions *)
GUI::usage = "GUI object";
(* Package level functions *)
BeginPackage["`Package`"];
guiImp1::usage = "row 1";
guiImp2::usage = "row 2";
makeGUI::usage = "builds the GUI";
EndPackage[];
(* Implementation *)
Begin["`Private`"];
guiImp1[] := {"lololol"};
guiImp2[] := {"lol2"};
makeGUI[ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  DynamicModule[{$packageLoaded},
   Dynamic@
    Framed[
     Grid[{
       guiImp1[],
       guiImp2[]
       },
      Alignment -> Left],
     ops,
     RoundingRadius -> 5, Background -> GrayLevel[.98], 
     FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[.8]
     ]
   ];
Format[e : GUI[ops : OptionsPattern[]]] :=
  Interpretation[
   DynamicModule[{},
    Dynamic[Refresh[GUI; makeGUI[ops], None]],
    SaveDefinitions -> True
    ],
   e
   ];
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

And now all `*Values` for the package will be stored in every `GUI` object. This is, of course, an expensive approach and should only be used for GUIs with a small number of expected instances.